# Tomcat on EasyApache in cPanel Suddenly Stopped Working Throwing 404s on All Pages

Tags: java, tomcat, cpanel, whm

Tomcat on EasyApache in cPanel Suddenly Stopped Working Throwing 404s on All Pages.

I've tried the usual, starting and stopping the Apache HTTPD and Apache Tomcat Linux services (on a CentOS 6 box) and even rebooted the whole server. Still no luck.

I'm a bit lost as to what to look for to try and fix this issue as nothing has changed at the application layer, so I have come to the conclusion that there must have been an automatic upgrade on either WHM or cPanel in the background that has thrown things out.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an automatic cPanel upgrade from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8.5 which broke everything. Had to get cPanel support involved to fix their mess. Well.... that was fun!